Who are these Phani and Ahi, that mentioned in Garuda Purana?
In this chapter of Garuda Purana, i noticed about the presiding naga devatas of Graha deities.

The sun is the presiding star of Sesha, the moon of Phani, Mars of Takshaka, Jupiter of Karkotyna, Venus of Padma and Mahapadma, Saturn of Shankha, and Rahu of Kuluka and Ahi.

We should know about Sesha, Takshaka, Karkotaka (named as Karkotyna), Padma, Mahapadma, and Kuluka/Kulika. But, Phani and Ahi are unknown.
So my question is, who are them? Did any other scriptures mention them?
